# Reliable Messaging with RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

I have an application that sends AMQP messages via RabbitMQ.  message sending is triggered on an http request.  Recently I have noticed that some messages appear to be getting lost (as in never delivered).  I also noticed that the list of channels being managed by the server is steadily increasing.  The first thing I have corrected is to close channels after they are no longer required.  However, I am still not sure my code is correctly structured to ensure delivery.  Two sections of code are below; the first is a section of a singleton that manages the connection (does not recreate on every call), the second is the sending code.  Any advice / guidance would be appreciated.

```
@Service
public class PersistentConnection {
    private static Connection myConnection = null;
    private Boolean blocked = false;

    @Autowired ApplicationConfiguration applicationConfiguration;
    @Autowired ConfigurationService configurationService;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
    }

    @PreDestroy
    private void destroy() {
        try {
            myConnection.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Connection getConnection( ) {
        if (myConnection == null) {
            start();
        }
        else if (!myConnection.isOpen()) {
            log.warn("AMQP Connection closed.  Attempting to start.");
            start();
        }
        return myConnection;
    }


    private void start() {
        log.debug("Building AMQP Connection");

        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        String ipAddress = applicationConfiguration.getAMQPHost();
        String password = applicationConfiguration.getAMQPUser();
        String user = applicationConfiguration.getAMQPPassword();
        String virtualHost = applicationConfiguration.getAMQPVirtualHost();
        String port = applicationConfiguration.getAMQPPort();

        try {
            factory.setUsername(user);
            factory.setPassword(password);
            factory.setVirtualHost(virtualHost);
            factory.setPort(Integer.parseInt(port));
            factory.setHost(ipAddress);
            myConnection = factory.newConnection();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        myConnection.addBlockedListener(new BlockedListener() {
            public void handleBlocked(String reason) throws IOException {
                // Connection is now blocked
                blocked = true;
            }

            public void handleUnblocked() throws IOException {
                // Connection is now unblocked
                blocked = false;
            }
        });
    }

    public Boolean isBlocked() {
        return blocked;
    }
}

/*
 * Sends ADT message to AMQP server.
 */
private void send(String routingKey, String message) throws Exception { 
    String exchange = applicationConfiguration.getAMQPExchange();  
    String exchangeType = applicationConfiguration.getAMQPExchangeType();

    Connection connection = myConnection.getConnection();
    Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
    channel.exchangeDeclare(exchange, exchangeType);
    channel.basicPublish(exchange, routingKey, null, message.getBytes());

    // Close the channel if it is no longer needed in this thread
    channel.close();
}
```

Comment: Can  `getConnection( )` called from more threads? if yes the code in not threadsafe.

Comment: An http request comes in which eventually invokes the getConnection() call.  So I guess it can.  I thought by making it a singleton that would address that issue.  What is the best way to improve the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
@Service
public class PersistentConnection {
    private Connection myConnection = null;
    private Boolean blocked = false;

    @Autowired ApplicationConfiguration applicationConfiguration;
    @Autowired ConfigurationService configurationService;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
      start(); /// In this way you can initthe connection and you are sure it is called only one time.
    }

    @PreDestroy
    private void destroy() {
        try {
            myConnection.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Connection getConnection( ) {
        return myConnection;
    }


    private void start() {
        log.debug("Building AMQP Connection");

        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        String ipAddress = applicationConfiguration.getAMQPHost();
        String password = applicationConfiguration.getAMQPUser();
        String user = applicationConfiguration.getAMQPPassword();
        String virtualHost = applicationConfiguration.getAMQPVirtualHost();
        String port = applicationConfiguration.getAMQPPort();

        try {
            factory.setUsername(user);
            factory.setPassword(password);
            factory.setVirtualHost(virtualHost);
            factory.setPort(Integer.parseInt(port));
            factory.setHost(ipAddress);
            myConnection = factory.newConnection();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        myConnection.addBlockedListener(new BlockedListener() {
            public void handleBlocked(String reason) throws IOException {
                // Connection is now blocked
                blocked = true;
            }

            public void handleUnblocked() throws IOException {
                // Connection is now unblocked
                blocked = false;
            }
        });
    }

    public Boolean isBlocked() {
        return blocked;
    }
}

/*
 * Sends ADT message to AMQP server.
 */
private void send(String routingKey, String message) throws Exception { 
    String exchange = applicationConfiguration.getAMQPExchange();  
    String exchangeType = applicationConfiguration.getAMQPExchangeType();

    Connection connection = myConnection.getConnection();
    if (connection!=null){
    Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
    try{
    channel.exchangeDeclare(exchange, exchangeType);
    channel.basicPublish(exchange, routingKey, null, message.getBytes());
    } finally{
      // Close the channel if it is no longer needed in this thread
       channel.close();
   }
```

}
    }

This could be enough, you have an connection with rabbitmq when the system starts.

If you  an lazy singleton, the code is just a bit different.

I suggest to not use `isOpen()` method, please read [here](http://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-java-client/v1.7.0/rabbitmq-java-client-javadoc-1.7.0/com/rabbitmq/client/ShutdownNotifier.html#isOpen()):

> isOpen
>
> boolean isOpen() Determine whether the component is currently open.
>   Will return false if we are currently closing. Checking this method
>   should be only for information, because of the race conditions - state
>   can change after the call. Instead just execute and try to catch
>   ShutdownSignalException and IOException Returns: true when component
>   is open, false otherwise

**EDIT****

Question 1:

What are you looking for is the HA client.

RabbitMQ java client by default doesn't support this features, since the version 3.3.0 supports only the reconnect,read [this](http://www.rabbitmq.com/news.html#2014-04-02T15:58:38+0100):

> ...allows Java-based clients to reconnect automatically after network
>   failure. If you want be sure about your messages you have to create an
>   robust client able to resists to all fails.

Generally you should consider the fails, for example:
what happen if there is an error during the message publish?

In your case you simply lose the message,You should re-queue the message manually.

Question 2:

I don’t know your code, but `connection == null` shouldn’t happen, because this procedure is called for first:

```
@PostConstruct
    private void init() {
      start(); /// In this way you can initthe connection and you are sure it is called only one time.
    }
```

Anyway you can raise an exception, the question is:
What do I have to do with the message that I was trying to send?

See the question 1

I’d like to suggest to read more about the HA, for example this:

- http://www.rabbitmq.com/ha.html
- https://www.rabbitmq.com/reliability.html
  And this for the client:
- https://github.com/jhalterman/lyra (I never used it)

Create a reliable system with rabbitmq is not complex, but you should know some basic concept.

Anyway .. Let me know!

Comment: Thank you very much for this.  I will work on it tonight and load the code up tomorrow and update you.

Comment: I am just starting to look at this and I have a couple of questions.  Firstly, what will happen if the RabbitMQ server is restarted (for example) - I assume that the connection will fail and will not automatically reconnect when the server starts?  Is there someway to automatically reconnect?  Also, I was thinking that the send method should probably throw an Exception if connection==null - does this make sense?

Comment: this has bee really helpful.  I have loaded the new code and it seems to be working well.  I have also read through the references - and found your book :).  I don' think my application really required Lyra, but I will keep it in mind for the future. Thank you again.

Comment: @skyman Do check out Lyra if reliability is an issue. Attempting to roll your own HA client is deceptively hard, and you either don't cover all the possible scenarios or you end up implementing something like Lyra :)

Comment: @Jonathan Thanks for the comment.  I still appear to be having minor issues - will look at Lyra